# Arabic in Titanium

Tags: utf-8, localization, titanium, arabic

I am working on an app where the alphabets are displayed in Arabic language. So once I have displayed all the alphabets in the normal individual forms; I would like to join them together in their respective form(start,middle,end).

How can I do this ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 natively supports arabic. For example:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window layout="horizontal" horizontalWrap="true" backgroundColor="white">
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="Name"/>
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="Last"/>
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="Middle"/>
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="First"/>
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="Indep."/>
        
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="alif"/>
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="ـا"/>
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="ـاـ"/>
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="اـ"/>
        <Button width="20%" height="30%" title="ا"/>
        
        <Button width="100%" height="30%" title="the school is new:  المدرسة جديدة"/>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: Screenshot of Arabic lettering]

So... You probably need to compile the alphabets into a single document (make sre to save as UTF-8 encoding) and then load / render that file itself.

Comment: But on my side, the user clicks on one of the forms which is then added to the textfield. For example : Once the starting letter is adde d in its normal form , the second letter added should in its middle form and should get connected to the previous letter in its respective way.

Comment: Can you show code of what you have tried? This sounds like all you would have to do is just add to the textfield, then just have a var that knows which form to add.